# i keep on getting an error message even after i run the troubleshoot for updates

Tags: windows-10, updates

15 April 2020 today when i ran the update i got the following message there were problems installing some updates, but we'll try again later
2020-02 cumulative update for.net framework 3.5 and 4.8 for windows 10 version 1909 (KB4537572)- error 0x8e5e0147
2020-04 cumulative update for windows 10 version 1909 for x86 based systems (KB4549951) - error 0x80070020
and when i run the troubleshooter for updates it tells me that it can't fix the problem

Comment: Run all the steps in the multi OS Microsoft Troubleshooter. KB971058

Comment: See this page>>>>>https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/windows-update-resources

Comment: @John that KB tool is no longer available from Microsoft.

Comment: Go to http://support.microsoft.com/KB971058 and it will take you to a good Microsoft site - I just did it

Comment: What was the last cumulative update that was actually successfully installed?

Comment: I highly recommend determine what the last cumulative update that was installed then run the script as explained [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/windows-update-resources).

Comment: when every you get an error message while trying to install updates you just need to refresh your computer and that problem will disappear